# Javascript web bluetooth connections not working on chromebook

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, chromebook

Im making a website for connecting to a bluetooth cutting device.

Im using the javascript web bluetooth api code.

I have tested on windows and apple and get no issues really. I can connect, and send the data to the machine. And I have tested it on chrome browser on all devices and it works except on chrome.

I am now testing on chromebook.
The bluetooth still connects to a device.
But when it comes to sending the data it returns the error

```
No Services matching UUID 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb found in Device.
```

Obviously these are all correct because they work on other OS.

Does anyone know why chromeOS might have different restrictions on bluetooth connections and where i can alter them?

I have tried changing some flags and no effect.
I will include below my log results from a windows machine and the chromebook.

```
Connection Process
Windows: 

>>> IMPORT NAVIGATOR
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 MODULE Lazy_ToString_ValueNotCreated
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 RRRRRRRDDDDDDDDAAAAAAAA
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.WebAssemblyJSObjectReference
bluetoothControls.js:4 >>>js XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX requestDevice
bluetoothControls.js:23 >>>js requestDevice 3333 device  BluetoothDevice {id: 'dRtgl8alva981A1jnk8b4g==', name: 'Portrait 3-0', gatt: BluetoothRemoteGATTServer, ongattserverdisconnected: null}
bluetoothControls.js:24 >>>js requestDevice 3333 device  Portrait 3-0
bluetoothControls.js:28 >>> Connected
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD Portrait 3-0
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 im device and im init device
bluetoothControls.js:69 START READ VALUE.JS
bluetoothControls.js:48 >>> GET DEVICES >>>
bluetoothControls.js:54 >>> DEVICE [object BluetoothDevice] >>>
bluetoothControls.js:55 >>> GOT DEVICE >>>


bluetoothControls.js:83 >>> ARRAY 80,111,114,116,114,97,105,116,32,51 >>>
bluetoothControls.js:69 START READ VALUE.JS
bluetoothControls.js:48 >>> GET DEVICES >>>
bluetoothControls.js:54 >>> DEVICE [object BluetoothDevice] >>>
bluetoothControls.js:55 >>> GOT DEVICE >>>

bluetoothControls.js:83 >>> ARRAY 80,111,114,116,114,97,105,116,32,51 >>>


ChromeOS:
>>> IMPORT NAVIGATOR
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 MODULE Lazy_ToString_ValueNotCreated
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 RRRRRRRDDDDDDDDAAAAAAAA
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.WebAssemblyJSObjectReference
bluetoothControls.js:4 >>>js XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX requestDevice
bluetoothControls.js:23 >>>js requestDevice 3333 device  BluetoothDevice {id: 'skGlrRzfXBcxQI6UHQboWA==', name: 'Portrait 3-0', gatt: BluetoothRemoteGATTServer, ongattserverdisconnected: null}
bluetoothControls.js:24 >>>js requestDevice 3333 device  Portrait 3-0
bluetoothControls.js:28 >>> Connected
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD Portrait 3-0
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 im device and im init device
bluetoothControls.js:69 START READ VALUE.JS
bluetoothControls.js:48 >>> GET DEVICES >>>
bluetoothControls.js:54 >>> DEVICE [object BluetoothDevice] >>>
bluetoothControls.js:55 >>> GOT DEVICE >>>


dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 Canvas not connected to bluetooth: No Services matching UUID 0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb found in Device.
dotnet.native.8.0.1.y3hnxyz8dw.js:8 undefined
```

I have tried reset my settings, turning on and off all bluetooth flags